# Calculating hours based on dates for weekend/weekday/public holiday

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been attempting to use networkdays.intl to calculate hours for a weekend/weekday and public holiday.

The calculation is correct except when the time starts in 1 day and ends in another day for a shift (IE: 9pm until 2am)

Formula used for weekday

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,D2,"0000011",$T$2:$T$7)*G2
```

Formula used for weekend

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(B2,D2,"1111100",$T$2:$T$7)*G2
```

Formula used for public holiday (basic)

```
=SUM(I2-Q2-R2)
```

Example sheet with highlighted cells causing the miscalculation.

[Calculating hours on dates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ydSctnD-sNJ1W7QcHaJb7yU52V03TMkX4uL0AYifsK0/edit#gid=1339850771)

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Q12:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(QUERY({TEXT(SEQUENCE(D12-B12+1, 1, B12), {"ddd", "#"}), 
 {1-C12; SEQUENCE((D12-B12+1)-2, 1, 1, ); E12}}, 
 "select Col3 
  where not Col1 matches 'Sat|Sun' 
    and not Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IFERROR(1/(1/T2:T)))&"'")*1), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

R12:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(IFNA(QUERY({TEXT(SEQUENCE(D12-B12+1, 1, B12), {"ddd", "#"}), 
 {1-C12; SEQUENCE((D12-B12+1)-2, 1, 1, ); E12}}, 
 "select Col3 
  where Col1 matches 'Sat|Sun' 
    and not Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IFERROR(1/(1/T2:T)))&"'"))*1), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

S12:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(SUM(IFNA(QUERY({TEXT(SEQUENCE(D12-B12+1, 1, B12), {"ddd", "#"}), 
 {1-C12; SEQUENCE((D12-B12+1)-2, 1, 1, ); E12}}, 
 "select Col3 
  where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, IFERROR(1/(1/T2:T)))&"'"))*1), "[h]:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It doesn't get the desired result.  The orig. formula adds an additional day, which was the same issue I encountered previously for column I initially.

Comment: This was the formula used to calculate the correct amount of hours, which I had trouble with originally.  I'm looking to expand this into a breakdown of weekday/weekend/public holiday where I'm falling short.   =IF(IF(C13=E13=TRUE,C13=E13,C13>E13)=TRUE,IFS(AND(C13=0,C13=E13),1,E13<C13,((1-C13)+E13),1=1,E13-C13)*DATEDIF(B13,D13,"D"),(IFS(AND(C13=0,C13=E13),1,E13<C13,((1-C13)+E13),1=1,E13-C13)*DATEDIF(B13,D13,"D"))+IFS(AND(C13=0,C13=E13),1,E13<C13,((1-C13)+E13),1=1,E13-C13))

Comment: @TTVH whats the desired result for S12 & S13 ?

Comment: desired result, Q12 = 46:00:00 R12 = 00:00:00 S12 = 00:00:00 Q13 = 10:00:00 R13 = 00:00:00 S13 = 00:00:00

Comment: @TTVH answer updated

Comment: thanks for the update. Using the formula gives Q12= 47:00:00 (46 would be correct) and Q13= 29:00:00 (10 would be correct)   Your formula is admittingly a bit out of my knowledge.